# How can I get results on the errors object and not an exception on a ChargeResponse in Square API? (PHP)

Tags: square-connect

I can’t seem to get any of the error conditions to show up in the Errors section of the ChargeResponse, they show up as exceptions.  Is this correct?
Consider the following

```
try {
  $result = $transaction_api->charge($access_token, $location_id, 
$request_body);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
}

  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($result); echo "</pre>";
```

When I pass in fake-card-nonce-declined to the transaction, the exception is caught and displayed as

```
[                                                                              object(stdClass)[9]
  public 'errors' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[10]
          public 'category' => string 'PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR' (length=20)
          public 'code' => string 'CARD_DECLINED' (length=13)
          public 'detail' => string 'Card declined.' (length=14)
]
```

and the var_dump of $result is NULL.
I was expecting this to be in the errors section of the $result.

Am I looking at this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP library is designed to throw exceptions for a non 200 response back from the server. You should keep your code in the try catch block, and keep in mind that the catch block will only be used for errors, while it will be ignored during healthy responses.

The errors object in the response object will not be filled out, unless you set it with something like this:

```
$result = new SquareConnect\Model\ChargeResponse();   
try {
  $result = $transaction_api->charge($access_token, $location_id, 
$request_body);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  $result->setErrors($e);
}

  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($result); echo "</pre>";
```

It is up to you to decide whether you need the errors to be filled out in your response object, or if you would like to use the built in exception handling.

Comment: Tristan, I tried your suggestion but it did not work.  When I pass in a nonce with value of "fake-card-nonce-ok", I get the expected response object.  When I change the nonce to "fake-card-nonce-declined", the php code stops execution on the $transaction_api->charge(...); line and the var_dump($result); after it isn't executed.

Comment: I think we have been having a communication issue. I tried out your code, and you are right. I'm updating my answer now.